# Printing PCB PDF parts size

Tags: pcb

I used 3 different PCB design software packages (Proteus, Eagle and Express PCB) and no matter what I'm doing the DIP-28N (or any other ICs) pins are printing bigger than actual IC pin number/size.

This is my printer setting:

[image: Printer setting]

I tried Microsoft print to PDF, taking an actual print on paper and used other "virtual printers"...

Why can't I print at a size identical to the PCB?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about using printers and printer software.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson is right, this isn't a problem with the PCB software, but potentially in your printer driver, settings, PDF software, or any number of things. Try other printers and look carefully at the "advanced" settings. "Fit to page" is often on by default, and should be disabled.

Comment: This is probably a wrong setting, but in desperation unless you're fighting an auto-sizing you can take calipers, measure the actual resulting size and compensate by the inverse percentage.  There isn't a specifically answerable question here.

Comment: Don't think about what it isn't doing, instead think about what it **is** doing. I've asked for a rectangle x by y mm, and it's printed a rectangle p x q mm. Great, now you know the scale. Do it again with a different amount of stuff on the pdf. Is the scale the same, or has it changed - is there an autoscaling fouling things up - or can you just use a fixed scaling to get the driver right?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it's related to printing PCBs so i think it's somehow related but you know better than me... i did some research and found many have this problem and since i posted an answer it's better to keep this question/answer.

Comment: @JYelton yes the problem was related to scaling, see the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with using Foxit Reader and changing the printer setting;

[image]

In case anyone else having same problem:

The **scale shouldn't be at 100%**, instead you should pick the "fit to printer margin" option.

Answer (score -1):

Don't print  direct from PCB layout software. It's an after-thought.

Instead, export the Gerber and open it up in Gerber reader software like DFM Now and print it from that.

Comment: How is this inherently better? How does converting the graphics to Gerber and using yet another software tool ensure that better prints can be obtained? It seems to me that if the printer drivers are broken it doesn't matter what tool you print from.

Comment: Hmm...I've printed directly from Eagle and ExpressPCB a lot and both have always come out perfectly to scale.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson My version of Allegro prints become non-sensical depending on your zoom when you print (the printout isn't actually zoomed but the level of zoom messes up the print to varying degrees.